# Two event in a single jsp tag

Tags: javascript, jsp

I want to make search button work on hitting enter button as well as on click on button.
I tried below code

Search:

```
<input id="search" type="text"> <input type="button"id="Btn" value="Search"  onkeypress="submitOnEnter(this,jQuery.Event);" onClick="Query()" /> 

<script type="text/javascript">  
     function submitOnEnter(inputElement, event) {  
         if (event.keyCode == 13) { 
             inputElement.form.submit();  
         }  
     }
</script>
```

But I am not able to make enter button searchable. The Onclick is working fine

Comment: You don't need those event handlers nor to check the keycode. If you put your inputs inside a well-formed form, it will behave exactly like you want without the need for any javascript. The form needs an `<input type=submit />`.

Comment: still not working. Its in the form

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
document.onkeypress = function keypressed(e){
  if (e.keyCode == 13) {
      document.forms['formname'].submit();
  }      
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code below should do exactly what you want without javascript.

```
<form .... >
    <input id="search" type="text"> 
    <button type="submit" value="Search">
</form>
```

The `type="submit"` on the `button` element (which is nicer then `<input type="submit" value="Search">`) will automatically take care of hitting an enter on the input.

The input and the button both have to be in the same form element though.